# C++ non const to const casting compilation error

Tags: c++, casting, const-cast

the below code doesn't compile

```
void aaa(const int **a) {
}

int *a[] = {new int[2]};
aaa(a);
```

I got "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int *[1]' to 'const int **" in VS2010 and similar error in gcc

when I change my declaration to:

```
int const *a[] = {new int[2]};
```

or

```
const int *a[] = {new int[2]};
```

it compiles, but I don't understand why it doesn't accept a non const variable declaration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of `a` is `int*[]`; the type you want is `int const**`.
`int*[]` converts to `int**`, but this will not convert implicitly to
`int const**`.  Consider the following code to understand why:

```
static int const ci = 42;

void aaa( int const** out )
{
    *out = &ci;
}

int
main()
{
    int* pa;
    aaa( &pa );     //  NOT LEGAL, because...
    *pa = 0;        //  would now change ci
    std::cout << ci << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, allowing this conversion would break const without
requiring a cast.

Depending on what you are doing, you might want to use:

```
void aaa( int const* const* out );
```

The implicit conversion of `int**` to `int const *const *` is legal.
(Otherwise, you'll need a `const_cast` somewhere, to tell the compiler
that you know what you're doing, and that it isn't really a problem.)

Comment: perhaps `aaa(&pa)` should be `aaa(pa)`

Comment: @tinybit or it's declaration should be `int* pa;`, and the use after the call should be `*pa = 0;`.  I'll edit to fix the code in my answer.  Thanks for spotting this.

Answer (score 2):

The function `aaa` expects a pointer-to-pointer-to-constant-int.
Your variable `a` is a pointer-to-pointer-to-int.
It is an error to assign the latter to the former.

both `int const *a[]` and `const int *a[]` is actually the same thing, matching the signature of `aaa`. If you tried `int * const a[]`, that would be a different type (pointer-to-constant-pointer-to-int) and you would trigger the type error again.

If you want your function `aaa` to take a constant-pointer-to-pointer-to-int, you need to write `aaa(int ** const a)`, but having a const-ness on parameter values has actually no effect on what you can call with.

---

**Edit:** *"But isn't constness added implicitly - done with an implicit cast? (Which is the actual question)"*

Constness can be implicitly added to the value you are passing, e.g.

```
void aaa(const int a) {}

int b=5;
aaa(b);
```

... or one level pointer

```
void aaa(const int* a) {}

int *b=new int;
aaa(b);
```

... but cannot be added deeper. For example this is invalid:

```
void aaa(const int** a) {}

int* b=new int;
int** c=&b;
aaa(c);
```

I think James Kanze explains it much better in his answer.